# How can I script moving files up one directory level with Terminal (or BBEdit worksheet)

Tags: terminal, bash, photos.app, fish

When exporting from Photos.app with settings that preserve the album & folder structure, every album folder contains dated folders for every date represented in that album, with the actual images inside those. An example export for this question gives this structure...

```
Export/
    Colour/
        11 November 2005/
            img_0440.jpg
        13 November 2005/
            pb130006_1_1.jpg
    Life/
        Creatures/
            12 November 2005/
                img_0453.jpg
        People/
            9 November 2005/
                img_0174.jpg
            10 November 2005/
                img_0181.jpg
            14 November 2005/
                pb140009.jpg
        Plants/
            10 November 2005/
                img_0404.jpg
                img_0408.jpg
            13 November 2005/
                img_0477.jpg
            14 November 2005/
                img_0625.jpg
```

What can I run in Terminal to traverse the contents of Export & move all found files up one directory level?

The desired result on my example would be...

```
Export/
    Colour/
        img_0440.jpg
        pb130006_1_1.jpg
    Life/
        Creatures/
            img_0453.jpg
        People/
            img_0174.jpg
            img_0181.jpg
            pb140009.jpg
        Plants/
            img_0404.jpg
            img_0408.jpg
            img_0477.jpg
            img_0625.jpg
```

A solution that works in `bash`, because I do a lot of my CL stuff in BBEdit which is `bash` only, or `fish` because that's my preferred shell in Terminal, would be preferred, but I'll work with other shells.

Comment: It's not my usual practice to cross-post, but this time I was a bit at a loss as to the most appropriate to post in. Would you kindly suggest which is best for this question? Update... deleted the SuperUser post following bmike's edit & comment here.

Comment: So, I’m going to at least remove the recursive, this seems more iterative, but regardless which approach a program takes, the result is clear without needing to specify a technique to flatten the hierarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested: remove the `echo` if it looks right:

```bsh
find ./Export -name '*.jpg' -print0 |
  xargs -0 sh -c 'for file; do echo mv "$file" "${file%/*}"/..; done' sh
```

The odd-looking trailing `sh` is required because it gets set as `$0` in the shell body, so the rest of the arguments fed to it by xargs can be easily iterated.

This will leave the empty directories. To list empty directories:

```bsh
find . -type d -empty -print
```

To delete empty directories:

```bsh
find . -type d -empty -print -delete
```

---

To not rely on the file extension:

```bsh
find ./Export -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 sh -c '
    for file; do
      case "$(file "$file")" in
        *"JPEG image data"*) echo mv "$file" "${file%/*}"/..;;
      esac
    done
  ' sh
```

Comment: Another way to list empty directories is with `find . -type d -empty -print` and then delete them with `find . -type d -empty -delete`.

Comment: @GrahamMiln, I've been using this to get rid of empty directories ;)

Comment: That works, but it depends on the the files all being JPEGs with lowercase extensions. Using `'*.*'` also seems to work, so I'll try it with some text exports with a greater variety of file types & names.